# Using Typescript building table from json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

How can I build html table from json? for negative value I want to bold the row. and display NJ warehouse first then CA

```
{
"action": "query",
"Time": 12,
"data": [
{
  "Product": "Iphone",
  "Price": 989,
  "Warehouse": "NJ"
},
{
  "Product": "Ipad mini",
  "Price": 429,
  "Warehouse": "NJ"
},
{
  "Product": "Iphone mini",
  "Price": 489,
  "Warehouse": "NJ"
},
{
  "Product": "Galaxy",
  "Price": -1,
  "Warehouse": "CA"
},
{
  "Product": "Galaxy mini",
  "Price": "595.99",
  "Warehouse": "CA"
}
]    
}
```

The result should be as below, first display all Warehouse=US then Warehouse=CA

US
Product         Price        Warehouse
Iphone           989.00      US 
Ipad mini        429.00      US 
Iphone mini      489.00      US 
CA
Product         Price        Warehouse
**Galaxy     -1          US **
Galaxy mini  595.99      CA

```
    <table width="200" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100" colspan="3">NJ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100">Product</td>
    <td width="50">Price</td>
    <td width="50">Warehouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ipad mini</td>
    <td>429.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Iphone mini</td>
    <td>429.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100"  colspan="3">CA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100">Product</td>
    <td width="50">Price</td>
    <td width="50">Warehouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Galaxy</td>
    <td><B>-1</B></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Galaxy mini</td>
    <td>595.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If this code is to run in a browser, I suggest you use an application framework with templating capabilities such as [Angular](https://angular.io/) or [React](http://reactjs.org/); if you get stuck, let us know what you tried and we can help.  If you just want to generate an HTML file as a standalone job, there are probably libraries suitable for that too, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: I want to get sample for above result using typescript or javascript

Comment: Do you want to run the code in a browser to display the table immediately, or do you want to generate an HTML file for later use?

Comment: I want to run in a browser immediately using jquery

Comment: OK.  jQuery is not the best tool for this job: it's designed to make individual modifications to a document rather than generate a large section of a document from a template.  I recommend using a framework that can do templating.  If you have an existing application, React will probably be easier to add than Angular.